# Chrome 21 and 1px difference very annoying bug

Tags: css, google-chrome

On [this site](http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/) the datepicker shows correctly in all browsers (IE8+, Firefox 14, Chrome 20 and Opera 12) but the newest update of Chrome, version 21, seems to have introduced a very annoying bug and I can't tell for the love of Darwin what the hell is going on and WHY?

------------**ALL & Chrome 20**-----------------------**Chrome 21 WTH!**------------

[image]

Any idea on why this is happening? Where is this bug coming from? I've tried toggling every single css property with devtools and nothing seems to make a difference. It even works in IE8, so this must be a Chrome bug.

**Edit:**
To clarify a bit more, when I position the datepicker to align it with the input, the top border of the datepicker aligns with the bottom border of the input. To collapse the borders I use `margin-top: -1px` in my css. The problem with the latest Chrome seems to be that it adds one more pixel to the space between the datepicker and the input, so the borders are not adjacent, they have a 1px distance in between before even collapsing them.

Comment: I noticed similar 1px errors (but in my case a missing pixel) in the newest Chrome dev versions (22) - I'd ignore it in the expectation that they fix it, those bugs probably don't last for long.

Comment: **@Lucero**. I can't even test Canary, doesn't seem to be working these days...

Comment: Ive noticed Chrome 21 seems to have a lot a little issues on different platforms.  Like on Arch Linux its HTLM5 video player is screwy and on Windows the rendering pipeline randomly renders black boxes... I kinda think some of there OpenGL stuff is messed up.

Comment: I reported the bug at [Chromium bugs](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=140738) if you want to follow

Answer (score 1):

I don't have permatent solution but you can give `margin-top:-2px;` to `ui-datepicker-div` for that browser.

Don't accept my answer. It's a temporary solution.

P.S. Can't analyze code from here, but looks like jquery's .height() function, gives height with borders for that version.

Comment: Yeah, well this is the first thing I thought of but hardly a solution as you say...

Comment: I found that also using debugging tools on Chrome version 21. `.ui-datepicker {

margin-top: -2px;`